# Passing world file information into a GeoTIFF correctly

Tags: qgis, python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, world-file

I have some drone imagery, for which I also have the associated world files. The world files contain the georeferencing information for each image. What I want is to transfer the image and geographical information into GeoTIFF files, from the original images and their world files.

So, in the code, what I am doing is like the following:

```
image_file = os.path.join(images_root_folder_path, image_name + ".JPG")
world_file = os.path.join(images_root_folder_path, image_name + ".jgw")

with rasterio.open(image_file, 'r') as original_image:
    world_file_contents = np.loadtxt(world_file)
    a_ = world_file_contents[0]
    d_ = world_file_contents[1]
    b_ = world_file_contents[2]
    e_ = world_file_contents[3]
    c_ = world_file_contents[4]
    f_ = world_file_contents[5]

    image_transformation = Affine(a=a_,
                                  b=b_,
                                  d=d_,
                                  e=e_,
                                  c=c_,
                                  f=f_)

    imagepath_geotiff = os.path.join(geotiffs_root_path, image_name + "_{0}.tif".format("abde"))
    with rasterio.open(
            imagepath_geotiff,
            'w',
            driver='GTiff',
            height=original_image.width,
            width=original_image.height,
            count=len(original_image.indexes),
            dtype='uint8',
            crs="EPSG:4326",
            transform=image_transformation) as georeferenced_image:
        for band_index in original_image.indexes:
            band_arr = original_image.read(band_index)
            georeferenced_image.write(band_arr, band_index)
```

Basically, I am opening the original source image, transfer the RGB bands into the GeoTIFF and additionally, I open the world file and read it line by line; the lines are corresponding to: A,D,B,E,C,F respectively for each line from 0 to 5. I am using Rasterio package for the GeoTIFF creation. The world files have been calculated in the coordinate system EPSG:4326. I also set the CRS of the GeoTIFF to this system. However, the same transformation would result in different views when opened in QGIS. The following is what I get when I open the JPG file with the associated world file:

[image]

And this is the GeoTIFF I produce with the code snippet above:
[image]

The left-top coordinate of both images do hold; however, it seems that the pixel width and height components in x and y dimensions are being interpreted differently for GeoTIFF:

[image]

For that reason, I thought that some specific permutation of the a, b, d and e elements of the affine transformation matrix would hold for the GeoTIFF, so I have also tried 4! different permutations as well, however they also resulted in different projections; the difference does not look to be solved that easily.

Is this a known issue, am I missing a required step here?

Comment: Won't the width and height of the raster change when you transform it

Comment: Using geographic (angular) units for georeferencing is very much not recommended. A local projection will produce far less RMS error.

Comment: Just open the original image, read it  and write it out to geotiff, rasterio will pick up the georeferencing from the world file automatically. If you want to reproject to a different CRS, warp the original to the output geotiff. https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/reproject.html#reprojecting-a-geotiff-dataset  Again, rasterio will read the georef from the world file.